# `declare` un-causing problems with missing functions/commands?

Tags: bash, shell-builtin

**summary:** If in `bash` I attempt to assign the output of a missing function to a previously-`declare`d (i.e., not {constant, read-only}) variable, I can detect the failure with "normal" tests. But if I attempt to assign the output of a missing function to a variable while `declare`ing it (e.g., to make the var {constant, read-only}), not only does the assignment not fail with "normal" tests, but I cannot force failure with "normal" builtins. How can I make the latter case fail?

**details:**

I recently ran into a problem in a much larger `bash` script, which I've attempted to distill into the following 2 scripts. Basically, I'm sorta-kinda doing TDD with `bash` ( `snark > /dev/null` ), so among other things

- I want missing commands/functions to fail fast
- I want to prevent rewriting constants

However, `bash` seems to be allowing me to assign the output of a missing function to a variable while `declare`ing the var. E.g., the following script (saved as `/path/to/assign_at_declare.sh` ) ...

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

function foo() {
    return 0
}

# function bar() {}               # does not exist!

declare ret_val=''
declare -r MESSAGE_PREFIX="$(basename "${BASH_SOURCE}"):"
declare -r ERROR_PREFIX="${MESSAGE_PREFIX} ERROR:"

echo -e "\n${MESSAGE_PREFIX} a naïve 1st attempt:\n"

declare -ir FOO1_VAL="$(foo)"   # this should succeed, and does
ret_val="${?}"
if   [[ "${ret_val}" -ne 0  ]] ; then
    >&2 echo "${ERROR_PREFIX} foo returned '${ret_val}', exiting ..."
    exit 3
elif [[ -z "${FOO1_VAL}"  ]] ; then
    >&2 echo "${ERROR_PREFIX} foo returned null, exiting ..."
    exit 4
else
    echo "${MESSAGE_PREFIX} FOO1_VAL='${FOO1_VAL}'"
fi

declare -ir BAR1_VAL="$(bar)"   # this should fail ... but doesn't
ret_val="${?}"
if   [[ "${ret_val}" -ne 0  ]] ; then
    >&2 echo "${ERROR_PREFIX} bar returned '${ret_val}', exiting ..."
    exit 5
elif [[ -z "${BAR1_VAL}"  ]] ; then
    >&2 echo "${ERROR_PREFIX} bar returned null, exiting ..."
    exit 6
else
    echo "${MESSAGE_PREFIX} BAR1_VAL='${BAR1_VAL}'"
fi

echo -e "\n${MESSAGE_PREFIX} get tough using \`set\` builtins:\n"
# see https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html
set -o errexit
set -o pipefail

declare -ir FOO2_VAL="$(foo)"   # this should succeed, and does
ret_val="${?}"
if   [[ "${ret_val}" -ne 0  ]] ; then
    >&2 echo "${ERROR_PREFIX} foo returned '${ret_val}', exiting ..."
    exit 3
elif [[ -z "${FOO2_VAL}"  ]] ; then
    >&2 echo "${ERROR_PREFIX} foo returned null, exiting ..."
    exit 4
else
    echo "${MESSAGE_PREFIX} FOO2_VAL='${FOO2_VAL}'"
fi

declare -ir BAR2_VAL="$(bar)"   # this should fail ... but doesn't
ret_val="${?}"
if   [[ "${ret_val}" -ne 0  ]] ; then
    >&2 echo "${ERROR_PREFIX} bar returned '${ret_val}', exiting ..."
    exit 5
elif [[ -z "${BAR2_VAL}"  ]] ; then
    >&2 echo "${ERROR_PREFIX} bar returned null, exiting ..."
    exit 6
else
    echo "${MESSAGE_PREFIX} BAR2_VAL='${BAR2_VAL}'"
fi

exit 0
```

... produces the following output:

```
assign_at_declare.sh: a naïve 1st attempt:

assign_at_declare.sh: FOO1_VAL='0'
/path/to/assign_at_declare.sh: line 27: bar: command not found
assign_at_declare.sh: BAR1_VAL='0'

assign_at_declare.sh: get tough using `set` builtins:

assign_at_declare.sh: FOO2_VAL='0'
/path/to/assign_at_declare.sh: line 56: bar: command not found
assign_at_declare.sh: BAR2_VAL='0'
```

This seems odd, since I do not observe this behavior if I attempt to assign the output from the missing function to a variable **after** `declare`ing the var (i.e., if the var is **not** {constant, read-only}) as in the following script (saved as `/path/to/assign_after_declare.sh` ) ...

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

function foo() {
    return 0
}

# function bar() {}           # does not exist!

declare ret_val=''
declare -i foo_val=0
declare -i bar_val=0
declare -r MESSAGE_PREFIX="$(basename "${BASH_SOURCE}"):"
declare -r ERROR_PREFIX="${MESSAGE_PREFIX} ERROR:"

echo -e "\n${MESSAGE_PREFIX} following works as expected\n"

foo_val="$(foo)"           # this should succeed, and does with/out `declare`
ret_val="${?}"
if   [[ "${ret_val}" -ne 0  ]] ; then
    >&2 echo "${ERROR_PREFIX} foo returned '${ret_val}', exiting ..."
    exit 3
elif [[ -z "${foo_val}"  ]] ; then
    >&2 echo "${ERROR_PREFIX} foo returned null, exiting ..."
    exit 4
else
    echo "${MESSAGE_PREFIX} foo_val='${foo_val}'"
fi

bar_val="$(bar)"           # this succeeds with `declare`, fails without
ret_val="${?}"
if   [[ "${ret_val}" -ne 0  ]] ; then
    >&2 echo "${ERROR_PREFIX} bar returned '${ret_val}', exiting ..."
    exit 5
elif [[ -z "${bar_val}"  ]] ; then
    >&2 echo "${ERROR_PREFIX} bar returned null, exiting ..."
    exit 6
else
    echo "${MESSAGE_PREFIX} bar_val='${bar_val}'"
fi

exit 0
```

... which produces the following output:

```
assign_after_declare.sh: following works as expected

assign_after_declare.sh: foo_val='0'
/path/to/assign_after_declare.sh: line 29: bar: command not found
assign_after_declare.sh: ERROR: bar returned '127', exiting ...
```

Is there a way to force `bash` to fail-fast when assigning **during** a `declare`? If so, I await your answer.

Alternatively, is `bash` Working As Designed? If so, please link to a reference; I tried searching this question, but my selectors were either incorrect or returned so many unrelated responses as to be useless.

Comment: What is 'un-causing problems'? It sounds nasty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`declare`'s return status is](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-declare):

> zero unless an invalid option is encountered, an attempt is made to define a function using `-f foo=bar`, an attempt is made to assign a value to a readonly variable, an attempt is made to assign a value to an array variable without using the compound assignment syntax, one of the names is not a valid shell variable name, an attempt is made to turn off readonly status for a readonly variable, an attempt is made to turn off array status for an array variable, or an attempt is made to display a non-existent function with `-f`.

As none of these situations apply, Bash is Working As Designed, as you put it.

[`$(bar)`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution) executes `bar` in a subshell, which exits with an error and no standard output. The substitution results in an empty string, which is interpreted as zero for an integer variable. [`declare` then returns 0, as documented](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-declare).

---

You *could* detect a failure by, for example:

```
declare -ir x="$(bar || echo failed running bar >&3)"
```

with fd 3 set up appropriately in advance. Such setup is left as an exercise to the reader.